# Springboot externalizing log4j configuration

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

In a springboot application, I have a single jar, and then a subdirectory config with application.properties, applicationContext.xml, and log4j...properties file.

I am trying to externalize the log4j config. The application.properties is externalized this way.

But, when springboot runs it is using the log4j config file from within the jar file.  By using the  -Dlog4j.debug option I can see that log4j uses my external file first, but when spring starts it overrides the log4j setting with the one in the jar.

here is an example startup (with all options)

```
java -Dlog4j.debug 
   -Dlogging.config="file:/opt/config/log4j-qa.properties" 
   -Dlog4j.configuration="file:/opt/config/log4j-qa.properties" 
   -jar /opt/myjarName.jar 
   --spring.config.location=/opt/config/
```

**on first startup log4j states**
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/opt/config/log4j-qa.properties

**then on springboot start**
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/opt/dms-events-api.jar!/log4j-qa.properties

but I want it to read only the external file file:/opt/config/log4j-qa.properties

Answer (score 0):

resolution:

In our application we had line
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
which then defined the log4j properties file from the classpath:

the simple solution
1. create a /config directory at the root of the api application and put the properties files there
2. remove the ImportResource line, it isn't needed now
3. add a line to the the application.properties file
 logging.config=file:config/log4j-${our environment var}.properties

the explanation
By creating a /config directory at the root of the project then 
we can work in eclipse as usual and find our properties files.
--and then to externalize configs
simply add a config directory off of where the application jar is and put properties files there.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems are there:

1. Configuration for externalise: - Tried and works below one for me in spring boot jar

   ```
   -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/Users/test/Any-Folder/log4j.properties
   ```
2. Spring logging takes over - for that you need to exclude the logging module. PFB the config for Gradle build.

   ```
   configurations {
        all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'   
   }
   ```

Comment: Do not forget to put `file:`