# Externalized configuration setting out of fat-JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications

I am looking for a way to purely externalize some configuration settings in Spring boot application. For example: when double clicked on the fat-JAR file then it loads configuration from that, say myConfig.config, file which is in the same folder in which the fat-JAR file is. Then read the configuration from there and deploy the web-app. One use case is reading the port number from the config file and start the web-app on port number specified in the config file. If port number needs to be changed then only config file needs to be updated and restart the web-app.

I know that it is possible in .NET. I tried this link[1], but it is specifying config file in command line. Also, the @PropertySource can be used but again it winds up being in fat-JAR. There is Spring Cloud Config as well but I think that it would be overkill for small application. There are lots of tutorials available but they use one of the above mentioned method.

So, Is there any way to achieve that?

If yes, then what are the steps/link for that?

[1] [Springboot externalizing log4j configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334130/springboot-externalizing-log4j-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is place an application.properties file at the same level as your jar.  Spring Boot will find and use the application.properties w/o anything extra.

Comment: Thank you @BrianY. Can we add multiple config files like that and update them on the fly?

Comment: You can make the change w/o rebuilding the jar but the application needs to be restarted to pick up the new values.  Also Spring has provisions for different profiles which can each have their own properties file.  See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_application_properties.htm